# configMap from dependency is not found

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have 2 charts.

```
└── charts
    ├── cm
    │   ├── Chart.yaml
    │   ├── templates
    │   │   └── configmap.yaml
    │   └── values.yaml
    └── micro
        ├── Chart.lock
        ├── Chart.yaml
        ├── charts
        │   └── cm-0.1.2.tgz
        ├── templates
        │   ├── NOTES.txt
        │   ├── _helpers.tpl
        │   ├── deployment.yaml
        │   ├── hpa.yaml
        │   ├── ingress.yaml
        │   ├── service.yaml
        │   └── serviceaccount.yaml
        └── values.yaml
```

`micro` is depending on `cm`.

```
dependencies:
- name: cm
  version: 0.1.2
  repository: "file://../cm/"
```

`cm` is actually configMap, which will be eventually shared across multiple microservices.

In `micro` `deployment.yaml` I have specified checksum in annotation, so whenever configMap is modified, pod will get restarted.

```
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
```

However, this yields to an error:

```
no template "micro/templates/configmap.yaml" associated with template "gotpl"
```

I don't have config map in `micro`. How can I specify configMap in dependency template the way that when I modify it in `cm` chart, deployment in `micro` will be restarted?

Comment: I've been asked this in a comment on another answer, and I think it's not possible: `.Files.Get` can't refer to things outside the immediate chart, and while you could call helper functions from the subchart, they'd be evaluated in the context of the parent. ConfigMaps aren't that expensive; could you create a new one in each context where it's needed?

Comment: @David Maze: the idea was to have one common config map with environment variables shared cross multiple charts. If I create multiple configMaps then first of all I don't need configMap and can just set those variables in each deployment and second, I will have to duplicate same variables in Values.yaml of each chart, which seems not good idea.

Comment: Similar requirement is mine also. Looking for a way to do it. I tried using the help of "../../" but that could not help as well.